# Grails + EXTJS without the plugin

Tags: grails, extjs

Since the Grails extjs plugin has apparently been discontinued due to licensing restrictions, how would I go about using the extjs library (which has a license) in my Grails app without the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the Ext JS files in `web-app/js` and include them in the GSP files as you would other JS source.